# Question about the Axiom of Infinity and "naming"/defining objects which are possibly not unique.

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

I'm taking a class in set theory following the text "Elements of Set Theory" by Herbert Enderton. I had a question about the construction of the naturals and the axiom of infinity.

As I understand it, the axiom of infinity says $\exists A (A \text{ Inductive})$ (assume I had already defined what it means to be an inductive set in first order logic). Then when Enderton constructs the natural numbers (page 68), he says

> Let A be an inductive set; by the infinity axiom it is possible to find such a set.

Then applies a subset axiom to construct the smallest inductive set, which we call $\omega$.

The specific line I take issue with is the line "let A be an inductive set". I had a couple questions.

1] What are we actually doing when we say "let x be an object satisfying P" in the context of set theory? What does "let" mean?

2] When, in the axiom of infinity, we give the name $A$ to the inductive set, is the letter $A$ now forever bound in the language of set theory to an inductive set which exists via the axiom of infinity? If I'm being super strict, is it the case that I should no longer use the letter "A" to refer to anything else? If not, how do I refer later to the specific set which exists via the axiom?

3] Suppose we either assume or prove that there is an object with a given property, but that object may not be the unique object with this property. For example, the property of being an inductive set. If I later want to "chose" any object - it doesn't matter which one - that has this property, how do I express this in the language of set theory?

Comment: In this instance, I would assume that, roughly speaking, the author means that all subsequent statements are in the form $\exists A, (A\text{ inductive} \land P)$.

Comment: The problem is that the book would like to take the intersection of all inductive sets but cannot because the inductive sets form a proper class not a set.  So it starts with an inductive set (any one, and you know at least one exists from the axiom) and call it $A$.  This use of $A$ in this context is restricted to this proof; if you want to use it for something else later you are free to do so, and the book does so on page 70 and then in another context on page 71.

Comment: @Henry There is no problem taking the intersection of a non-empty proper class in set theory. If $C$ is a proper class and $X\in C$, then $\bigcap C$ is a set defined by $\{x\in X\mid \forall Y\in C\, x\in Y\}$.

Comment: Maybe you can shoehorn the following into ZFC theory. If you assume the existence of any Dedekind-infinite $X$, you can prove the existence of a $N\subset X$ and function $S: N\to N$ and element $x_0\in N$ such that $(N, S, x_0)$ is a Peano structure. From set theory, only subsets and Cartesian products are required. It can also be shown that all Peano's Structures are essentially the same structure (i.e. order isomorphic?).

Comment: @Henry I understand that the use of the letter A is restricted to this proof in practice, but I'm not sure why we're allowed to have the same letter refer to multiple things; in the context of a for all statement I would understand it more, but the specific A defined by an existential quantifier, so it seems like it refers to a single object.

Basically, I'm fine if the answer is "in practice we should be able to reuse letters" but I'd like to know if there is a way to avoid this in pure logic (maybe we have some sense of scope of definitions like programming languages?)

Comment: When we say "let x be an object satisfying P", we are applying "existential instantiation/elimination". Depending on your proof system, this may be built in or derived. It's good to make sure you understand everything that's being claimed, but I think you may be overthinking the question about variable names. Insofar as mathematical logic is concerned, all that's important is that the argument *could* in theory be written down in whatever proof system. It's straightforward to fix naming conflicts by just using different names. In proof assistants like Lean you do indeed see scoping mechanisms.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It goes like this.  Let $x=\Bbb{N}_A$ be the relation defined by a formula whose free variables are $x,A$ and says
$$\text{Inductive}(A)\land\forall y(y\in x\leftrightarrow(y\in A\land(\forall z(\text{Inductive}(z)\rightarrow y\in z))))$$
what this says is that $A$ is inductive, and $x$ is the subset separated out of $A$ as all the elements of $A$ that are members of all inductive sets.

Now you prove: $\forall A\;\text{Inductive}(A)\rightarrow(\exists x\, x=\Bbb{N}_A)$

To prove this you introduce a new constant $A$, assume $A$ is inductive, then use comprehension to show $x=\Bbb{N}_A$ exists.  Finally, use the logical rule of universal generalization that for all inductive $A$, $\Bbb{N}_A$ exists.

Next stage: $\forall A\forall B\forall x\forall y\;(\text{Inductive}(A)\land\text{Inductive}(B)\land x=\Bbb{N}_A\land y=\Bbb{N}_B)\rightarrow x=y$

In other words, that the $\Bbb{N}_A$ does not depend on the inductive $A$ you start with.  To show this, let $z\in\Bbb{N}_A$.  Then $z$ is in $A$ and $z$ is in every inductive set.  Since $B$ is inductive, $z\in B$.  Therefore $z$ is in $B$ and in every inductive set, so $z\in\Bbb{N}_B$.  This proves $\Bbb{N}_A\subseteq\Bbb{N}_B$.  By a symmetric argument, $\Bbb{N}_B\subseteq\Bbb{N}_A$.  By the axiom of extensionality, $\Bbb{N}_A=\Bbb{N}_B$.

Finally define $x=\Bbb{N}$ iff $\exists A\;\text{Inductive}(A)\land x=\Bbb{N}_A$.  Using existential instantiation, by the axiom of infinity, there exists an inductive $A$.  Then $\Bbb{N}$ exists and is unique by the results above.

Comment: I think this makes sense. I'd still like to know a little bit more about the general case (eg: my 1st & 3rd question) though, which is why I haven't accepted it as the answer.

Also, in your "final stage", could we delete the "$\text{Inductive}() \land \text{Inductive}()$" part, because the definition of the relation already captures that?

Comment: @Lukrau: I added omments how to prove the uniqueness.  Also, the axiom of infinity is used in the last part to show $\Bbb{N}$ exists.  You are right that there are some redundant qualifications of $\text{Inductive}(\ldots)$.  It doesn't affect the logic, and is only important if we're looking for the shortest formula/shortest proof.  I left it in as a reminder we're only interested in making statements about inductive sets.